# Laravel eloquent relationships (category with last posts)

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

i have multiple categories and each category has many posts, i want fetch 4 last posts for each category, i use this code:

```
$catsWitposts= $this->categories->with(['posts' => function($query){
                        $query->where('show', '=', 1);
                        $query->limit(4);
                        $query->orderBy('created_at','desc');
                    }])->get();
```

but this code show 4 posts for all category

query result should be display:

```
cat-01
 post-01
 post-02
 post-03
 post-04
cat-02
 post-05
 post-06
 post-07
 post-08
cat-03
 post-09
 post-10
 post-11
 post-12
....
```

thanks

Comment: This should work, I expect this would return all categories with last 4 posts, is that not right ?

Comment: this work but only show 4 last post in post table no 4 post for each cat

Answer (score 0):

An example

```
//Grab all categories
$categories = Category::all();

//This array will contain our result
$latest_posts_by_category = [];

//We use this array to save each post id that we have already collected
//in order to avoid to put it twice.
//Remember that some posts may belongs to many categories.
$ids = [];

//For each category we grab the latest post with the latest first associated category
//(Note that you can collect all associated categories if you want by remove the first() in the closure)
foreach($categories as $category){
    $post = Post::with(['categories' => function($query){
        $query->latest()->first();
    }])
    ->online() //You may have a custom method like this.
    ->latest()
    ->whereHas('categories', function($query) use($category) {
        $query->whereName($category->name);
    })->take(1)->first();

    //We take in account the fact that
    //some posts may belongs to many categories.
    //Obviously, we don't want to put it twice
    if(!in_array($post->id, $ids)){
        $latest_posts_by_category[] = $post;
        $ids[] = $post->id;
    }
}

//You can now use $latest_posts_by_category as you want
```